# How to update specyfic element generated by ngfor

Tags: angular

I have nested component 
In first component i have

```
<div class="single-proposal-wrapper" (mouseover)="showCheckBox(request.id)" (mouseout)="hideCheckBox(request.id)"> 
  <div [id]="request.id" class="proposal-checkbox" (click)="toggleRequestState($event)"></div>
  <app-documents-list
    [reqdocuments] = "documents"
    [reqId] = "request.id"
  ></app-documents-list>
</div>
```

this is app-docuemnt-list

```
<div>
<app-document-tile
  *ngFor="let doc of reqdocuments"
  [rdocument]="doc"
  [reqId] = "reqId"
></app-document-tile>
</div>
```

and that app-document-tile

```
  <div class="item chx-approve">
    <checkbox #rdocument.id [checked]="isCheckedApproved" (change)="approveDoc(rdocument.id)"></c-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="item chx-reject">
    <checkbox #rdocument.id [checked]="isCheckedRejected" (change)="rejectDoc(rdocument.id)"></c-checkbox>
  </div>
```

when I click checkbox with class="proposal-checkbox" update specfic single app-doucment-tile (all-approved-checkbox) generated by *ngfor in app-document-list.

I should bind nested component using some id and passing this id through `@Input` `@Output` or maybe using `Observable`? I would update only one element generated by `ngfor`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an index reference into your *ngFor :

```
<div *ngFor=let item of items; let i = index">
  <child-component [id]="i"></child-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

trackBy will sort your problem

When items are added, moved, or removed in the iterable, the directive must re-render the appropriate DOM nodes. To minimize churn in the DOM, only nodes that have changed are re-rendered.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

then implement your trackByFn function as per your requirement